# Call Base class fun() in using "this" keyword (when a derived class is presen)

Tags: c#

I have the following code snippet

```
Class Parent
{
    public override String ToString()
    {
            return "in Parent";
    }

    public virtual void printer()
    {
           Console.write(this.ToString());
    }
}

Class Child : Parent
{
    public override String ToString()
    {
            return "in Derived";
    }

    public override void printer()
    { 
           base.printer();
           Console.write(this.ToString());
    }
}
```

in Main I have

```
Parent p = new Derived();
p.printer();
```

The output comes as "In Derived" 2 times. This is expected as most overridden method is called.

But, is it possible to call the ToString() method of the base class, in this case instead of the base calling the derived one?

Comment: Welcome to the fun of virtual methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Form MSDN:

> When a virtual method is invoked, the run-time type of the object is
>   checked for an overriding member. The overriding member in the most
>   derived class is called, which might be the original member, if no
>   derived class has overridden the member.

So even if you cast to `Parent`, the object is still a `Child` so that override will apply.  The problem is that you're calling `ToString()` from the parent class which has been overridden, so there's no way to get to it if the instance is a `Child`.

One way to get around it is to create a separate private function instead of using `ToString()`:

```
public class Parent
{
    public override String ToString()
    {
        return ToStringPrivate();
    }

    private string ToStringPrivate()
    {
        return "in Parent";
    }

    public virtual void printer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.ToStringPrivate());
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public override String ToString()
    {
        return "in Derived";
    }

    public override void printer()
    {
        base.printer();
        Console.WriteLine(this.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* get around this by using the [new](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) keyword, rather than overriding ToString() in your Child class.

Then, when your object is referenced as a `Child` (or a child of `Child`), ToString() will map to `Child.ToString()`.  When it is cast as a base object (such as `Parent`), ToString() will map to `Parent.ToString()`.

I don't think this is necessarilly good practice though, especially with the ToString() function.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add a new method in Child:

```
public override string BaseToString()
{
     return base.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've touched on the solution in your original question code.  You just need to call base.ToString() directly.  Your base.printer() call is still calling this.ToString() which is going to call the overridden version from the Child class.